# cannot read property of undefined although with checking

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I feel want to cry stuck in this for hours.

why would this code return error of `cannot read property overwrite_date' of undefined`?!

```
for (var i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {

  console.log(data[i]) //return 3 item, no null or undefined value at all

  if(data[i]){

    let date = moment(data[i].overwrite_date).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you show us your `data`?

Comment: `temp` and `data` probably have different lengths.

Answer (score 2):

You are iterating `temp` instead of `data`.

Change this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
```

To this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                     ▲
```

Comment: there's nothing wrong with that, i want to iterate temp and do splice of temp using data.

Comment: @GialaJefferson: Well, something is wrong, otherwise you wouldn't get the error. The error seems to indicate that `temp` and `data` have different lengths or that `data` doesn't have numeric properties. Since your example is incomplete, there is not much we can do except guess.